# Update column value for each row by the values of other columns, avoiding deadlocks

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, deadlock

Experts, need help here.

I have a single table **tbl_stock_data**, for which I am trying to update a column "INBOUND_STOCK_LVL" using the values from columns "INBOUND_STOCK_LVL" and "OUTBOUND_STOCK_LVL"
such that:

```
INBOUND_STOCK_LVL = INBOUND_STOCK_LVL - (INBOUND_STOCK_LVL - OUTBOUND_STOCK_LVL)
```

Table View
[image]

I've written a query as follows:

```
UPDATE tbl_stock_data t1, 
       ( SELECT STORE_EXT_ID, INBOUND_STOCK_LVL, OUTBOUND_STOCK_LVL, 
                ORG_ID, INTEGRATION_PARTNER 
        FROM tbl_stock_data 
        WHERE STORE_EXT_ID = 'STOCK1' 
        AND INTEGRATION_PARTNER = 'fortnox' 
        AND ORG_ID = 'asdsg-23ewfsd-2342'
        ) t2
    SET t1.INBOUND_STOCK_LVL = t2.INBOUND_STOCK_LVL - (t2.INBOUND_STOCK_LVL - t2.OUTBOUND_STOCK_LVL) 
WHERE t1.STORE_EXT_ID=t2.STORE_EXT_ID 
AND t1.INTEGRATION_PARTNER=t2.INTEGRATION_PARTNER 
AND t1.ORG_ID=t2.ORG_ID
```

But this query sets the column to **0**

Before this, I was using a simple query (given below) that was working fine but it started creating deadlocks for the larger data set

```
UPDATE tbl_stock_data 
    SET INBOUND_STOCK_LVL = INBOUND_STOCK_LVL - (INBOUND_STOCK_LVL - OUTBOUND_STOCK_LVL) 
WHERE STORE_EXT_ID = 'STOCK1' 
AND INTEGRATION_PARTNER = 'fortnox' 
AND ORG_ID = 'asdsg-23ewfsd-2342'
```

**Note:**
single record can be obtained by PRODUCT_ID, STORE_EXT_ID, ORG_ID and INTEGRATION_PARTNER

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_stock_data` (
  `ORG_ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_EXT_ID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WAREHOUSE_ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `WAREHOUSE_EXT_ID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STORE_ID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STORE_EXT_ID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INBOUND_STOCK_LVL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OUTBOUND_STOCK_LVL` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OUTBOUND_STOCK_DELTA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INTEGRATION_PARTNER` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_CREATED` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_MODIFIED` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ORG_ID`,`PRODUCT_ID`,`WAREHOUSE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```